# Unable to use the "cmd" command to install bower and yeoman, after configured

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, bower-install

My "cmd" command like through this error while I try to install the bower or yeoman from npmjs site. here is the error:

```
D:\bow>npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo EN
OTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo" "grunt-cli" "bower"

npm ERR! cwd D:\bow
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\bow\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

My user name is "mb112830" and the password is "TECHM@112830", my server is "msat" and port is 80 so, to check the config of my npm it showing like this:

```
D:\bow>npm help config

D:\bow>npm config list
; cli configs
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"

; userconfig C:\Users\mb112830\.npmrc
https-proxy = "http://mb112830:TECHM%40112830@msat:80/"
proxy = "http://mb112830:TECHM%40112830@msat:80/"
regisry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\mb112830\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
; cwd = D:\bow
; HOME = C:\Users\mb302811
; 'npm config ls -l' to show all defaults.
```

all are correct. I i set the environment variable to my computer property too. what else i need to do further to checkout the npm modules directly using "cmd" commands?

Any one help me to sort this issue please? if find anything wrong please highlight.

Thanks in advance!

**Here is the information what my '.npmrc' file contains**

```
    proxy = http://"mb302811:TECHM@302811"@msat:80/
    https-proxy = http://"mb302811:TECHM@302811"@msat:80/
    registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like problem is due to "@" in your password.
Try with "quotes" around username and password.

```
npm config set proxy http://"user:p@ss"@proxy:port
```

Comment: sure let me try and get back to you.

Comment: I updated. still getting error only. is it need to update in the systems env. variable as well?

Comment: Could you please paste your .npmrc file. Likely its in c:\users\<username>\.npmrc

Comment: sure. I added the details to question, what my .npmrc file contains. please check.

Comment: Hi Kiran Pagar can you help me to sort this issue please?